# Electrostatics and Gauss law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

How can we prove that surface integral of the electric fieldfor a point charge that is outside a gaussian surface,
$$\int\mathbf E\cdot\,\mathrm d\mathbf S,$$ without actually using the concept of flux?

Comment: You can prove this with a fairly difficult intigration

Comment: From what assumptions do you want to prove this claim?

Comment: I can give you a quick answer. IntigrationE.ds is total number  of electric field lines passing through the surface but we know that gaussian surface is closed and the charge is outside the the gausssian surface .So total number of field line passing through is is equal to total number of lines exiting from it hence net E.ds is 0

Comment: @Sourabh  isn't it related to flux

Comment: Yes it is related to flux

Comment: @ACuriousMind  i wanted to prove it using basic electrostatics

Comment: @Sourabh Please use answers, not comments, for answers.

Comment: Can you specify the case in which you want to prove it

Comment: Any random gaussian surface

Comment: $\int E\cdot dS$ is the definition of flux.  How can you prove it is zero without using its definition?

Comment: @garyp i was wondering if there exists a proof using basic electrostatics and coulombs law

Comment: But how can you even talk about flux *at all* without referencing its definition?   I can talk about an automobile because I have a definition of "automobile" implicit in my memory.   How can I talk about a "Xxfghold"  without defining what a "Xxfghold" is?  How can I prove flux is zero without knowing what flux is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start from Coulomb's law: $$\vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$
where we take $\vec{\mathbf{r}}$ to be our coordinate, and $\varepsilon_0$ to be the vacuum permittivity.

Of course, you should be able to see how we can express this same law in terms of the charge *density*, instead of the charge itself, through integrating over space: $$\vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(\vec{\mathbf{r}}_0)}{||\vec{\mathbf{r}}_0-\vec{\mathbf{r}}||^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}~\mathrm{d}^3\vec{\mathbf{r}}$$

where $\rho$ is the aforementioned charge density. Here, we can take as a theorem the divergence of an inverse-square vector field to be $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\frac{1}{r^2}\vec{\mathbf{r}} = 4\pi\delta(\vec{\mathbf{r}})$$

Using this, we now can take the divergence of our charge density-defined electric field equation: $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon_0}\int\rho(\vec{\mathbf{r}})\delta(\vec{\mathbf{r}}_0-\vec{\mathbf{r}})~\mathrm{d}^3\vec{\mathbf{r}}$$

which is obviously $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) = \frac{\rho(\vec{\mathbf{r}})}{\varepsilon_0}$$

By the divergence theorem, we can see that this is equivalent to $$\oint \vec{\mathbf{E}}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{\mathbf{S}} = \frac{Q}{\varepsilon_0}$$

which is your desired result.